# Html content not showing up after if statement in Django

Tags: python, html, django

Im having some issues with my html content not showing up after putting in some `{% if %}` `{% endif %}` statements in my templates

I have this snippet in my code where I display the checkout table if and only if the current user's username matches the one from my Order model. (order.customer_name has a foreign key that is set to the current users username)

```
{% for order in latest_order %}
    {% if user.username == order.customer_name %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ order.order_name }}</td>
      <td>
        <form method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <button type="submit" name="remove_quantity" value="{{ order.id }}" class="mr-3 btn 
    btn-outline-info">-</button>
          {{ order.order_quantity }}
          <button type="submit" name="add_quantity" value="{{ order.id }}" class="ml-3 btn btn- 
     outline-info">+</button>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>${{ order.order_individual_price }}</td>
      <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <th><button type="submit" name="delete" value="{{ order.id }}" class="btn btn- 
     danger">Delete Item</button></th>
      </form>
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}`
```

I tried the following to see if it prints out the same username, which it does

```
<h1>{{ user.username }}</h1>
{% for order in latest_order %}
<h1>{{ order.customer_name }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

[Picture of the page with user.username and order.customername as h1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOvFi.png)

When I delete the if statement, this is what the website SHOULD look like

[Proper working table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieTLC.png)

Im pretty sure I'm missing something very obvious, Any help is appreciated!

Comment: order.customer_name needs the for loop otherwise it wont know what order is

Comment: try using [`ifequal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal-and-ifnotequal)

Comment: What kind of field is ```customer_name```? Is it a fk pointing to user?

Comment: Wrong design. You should filter the queryset (using either `Order.objects.filter(...)` or the reverse relation from user to orders) in the view, not return the whole table and use a condition in the template